# strcmp says seemingly identical string are not equal

Tags: c, strcmp

I am using `strcmp` to compare two strings. `lhs` is coming from a filestream via `fgets`. `rhs` is being created generated by a for loop to be a sequence of `n-1` whitespaces.

---

#### Example

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  size_t n = 10;
  char rhs[n];

  memset(rhs, ' ', n - 1); // Fill with spaces using memset()
  rhs[n-1] = 0; // Add NUL terminator

  printf("len=%zu\n", strlen(rhs));

  char lhs[n];

  FILE* file = fopen("test", "r");
  fgets(lhs, sizeof(lhs), file);
  printf("read=%s\n", lhs);

  return 0;
}
```

---

When using gdb, I will find that I have two strings that appear identical (I used gdb's `print` for this):

`lhs` = `"   "`

`rhs` = `"   "`

Yet, `strcmp(lhs, rhs) != 0`. This should return a `0` indicating that the strings are identical, but instead I get some other non-zero value.

Why aren't these strings considered equal?

Comment: Print out each `char` of `lhs` and `rhs` up to `n-1` chars and see which one is different between them. And BTW, you said `lhs` was read by `fgets`, but your pseudocode shows `rhs` being read instead. You should show your *real* code, not pseudocode.

Comment: The size of `rhs` is `n-1`, but you attempt to read `n` bytes into it. Won't go well.

Comment: Where is the `null` terminator?

Comment: `fgets()` also leaves the trailing newline, if there is one on the line it reads.  How are you viewing your string contents?

Comment: Note that `fgets` retains the newline which you must remove before a comparison.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `fgets` will read in `n-1` according to the reference. EDIT: I made a typo. @Weather There isn't one. I'm an amateur C programmer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Within CLI GDB. I am simply using `print rhs` and `print lhs`

Comment: It really needs a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the input, and how it is getting it. Note that the limit passed to `fgets` includes the `null` terminator, which will always be present in the filled string.

Comment: You've got it backwards. The allocation should be `lhs[n]` and then `fgets(lhs, n-1, file);` You're reading N+1 bytes (including NUL terminator) into an N-1 sized buffer.

Comment: @tadman I went for minimal, I forgot the complete and verifiable evidently.
Also, using `printf`, `rhs` is outputting a weird character `�PV`

Comment: If you want to fill up a buffer with spaces consider using [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) instead of this loop.

Comment: @tadman I followed your suggestion with `memset` and that corrected my problem. I must have been getting some unexpected output with `printf` since I did not have a null terminator.

Comment: Remember when working with C style strings, **always append a NUL terminator**. `rhs` does not have one set here. In C when a variable is defined *it is not initialized* unless a value is assigned, instead it is left in an uninitialized state. That may be random values, it may be zero, it may be some other value that got left there by chance. If you ever want to use a variable, initialize it before use.

Comment: Post a [mcve] to save your and us all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned up this code to create a *complete, minimal example* looks like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  size_t n = 10;
  char rhs[n];

  memset(rhs, ' ', n - 1); // Fill with spaces using memset()
  rhs[n-1] = 0; // Add NUL terminator

  printf("len=%zu\n", strlen(rhs));

  char lhs[n];

  FILE* file = fopen("test", "r");
  fgets(lhs, sizeof(lhs), file);
  printf("read=%s\n", lhs);

  return 0;
}
```

Where here it's important to *not* assign from `fgets`, that's a warning if you have `-Wall` turned on.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up. I finally understand what a true complete, minimal example looks like now. As others suggested, the lack of a null terminator was my issue.

Answer (score 2):

The string that is entered into your buffer is not the exact same, and you neglecting to add the null terminator means that the string programs will continue reading the string into a buffer until they find a null terminator, running the following code shows us this:

```
size_t n = 5;
char lhs[n];
char rhs[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    rhs[i] = ' ';
for(int i = 0; rhs[i]; i++)
    printf("| %d ", rhs[i]);
```

Output:

> | 32 | 32 | 32 | 32 | unknown values ..., could be 0, but until then still part of the array

You should think of an array as a memory address, especially when passing it to a function

You should write it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    rhs[i] = ' ';
rhs[n-1] = '\x00'; // null terminator
```